# Writing in windows 7 registry

Tags: c#, windows-7, registry

Would Someone Tell Me How I Can Create New Registry Key In Windows 7. Once I Tried I Got This Message "Access Denied".

Thanks
Afshin

Comment: What key are you trying to create?

Answer (score 2):

If you run the application as admin this will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CreateSubKey` method of [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class for this purpose. But you should have required permissions to do so. Do you have administrative rights? Also try by lowering the UAC level

As MSDN says it can cause several exceptions

```
 SecurityException  
    The user does not have the permissions required to create or open the registry key.

 UnauthorizedAccessException    
    The RegistryKey cannot be written to; for example, it was not opened as a
    writable key , or the user does not have the necessary access rights.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be UAC problem. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [working with the windows registry](http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7security/working-with-the-windows-registry/)